# Isomorphism on quadratic integrable functions on interval

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

> > Show that for all $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$, $u\mapsto v=e^{\alpha x}u$ is an isomorphism on $L^2([-M,M])$ with homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions.

As far as I see this means that for $u\in L^2([-M,M])$ with $u(-M)=u(M)=0$, I have to prove that $H\colon L^2([-M,M])\to L^2([-M,M]), H(u)=e^{\alpha x} u$ fulfills

- (1) $H$ is linear
- (2) $H$ is surjective
- (3) $\forall u,w\in L^2([-M,M]): \langle u,w\rangle_{L^2}=\langle H(u),H(w)\rangle_{L^2}$

**(1)** $H(au+bw)=e^{\alpha x}(au(x)+bw(x))=ae^{\alpha x}u(x)+be^{\alpha x}w(x)=a H(u)+bH(w)$

Not sure about (2) and (3).

For (2) I think it is to Show that $e^{\alpha x}u\in L^2([-M,M])$ implies $u\in L^2([-M,M])$.

Comment: For $\alpha \neq 0$, $H$ is definitely not unitary. Consider for $M = \frac{\pi}{2}$ the functions $u(x) = \cos x$ and $v(x) = \sin (2x)$. Then $\langle u, v \rangle = 0$ since $u$ is even and $v$ odd. But since $u(x)v(x) > 0 \iff x > 0$, and $e^t > 1 \iff t > 0$, we have $\alpha \cdot\langle H(u), H(v)\rangle > 0$ for $\alpha \neq 0$. The word "isomorphism" must mean "linear isomorphism" and not "unitary isomorphism" for the claim to be true.

Comment: @DanielFischer A linear isomorphism is a function that is linear and bijective?

Comment: A unitary isomorphism between two Hilbert space $H_1, H_2$ is a linear bijective map $U \colon H_1 \to H_2$ such that $\langle x,y\rangle_{H_1} = \langle U(x), U(y)\rangle_{H_2}$ for all $x,y \in H_1$. If we drop the condition that the map preserves the inner product we get a linear isomorphism (actually, in the context we want the map to be continuous, so we get an isomorphism in the category of topological vector spaces, but my main point was that the map in question isn't unitary).